# postgres array and rails 4 erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql

i have a view in my postgres database that returns an array on my `frequencies` column. unfortunately, it sometimes returns values like `{NULL}` (due to the raw data).

in my rails view, i have something like:

```
dataset = [
    <% @item.each do |i| %>
        {   
            name: "<%= i.device %>" 
            lng: <%= i.longitude %> 
            lat: <%= i.latitude %>
            frequencies: <%= i.frequencies.to_s.html_safe %>
        },
    <% end %>
]
```

which appears to work great - except when it reaches a record that contains `{NULL}`:

in the javascript console it shows:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: nil is not defined
```

and in the html it shows:

```
  ...
  }, {
    name: "blah",
    lng: -122.2,
    lat: 37.4,
    frequencies: [nil]
  }, { 
  ...
```

i could fix this by iterating through the list in the controller, but i think this would be rather long winded (and a waste of cycles).

is there a way i can get the erb to output the 'correct' `[]` in (instead of `[nil]`) json when it's null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <%= i.frequencies.compact %>
```

[compact](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-compact-20) example:

```
 [nil].compact #=> []
 [1,2, nil, 3, nil].compact  #=> [1,2,3]
```